# Bash globbing range in home dir shows content of subdirectories

Tags: bash

When I am using `ls [A-Z]*` in my home directory in the bash shell (5.1.8(1)) then it shows me not only the files in my home directory, but also of the subfolders.
Why is that and is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? The regular expression `[A-Z]*` means "every possible amount of an uppercase character", while zero is also a possible amount, so in fact, this means nothing. What's wrong with simple `ls`?

Comment: @Dominique That's a glob wildcard, not a regex. It selects files whose name starts with an uppercase ASCII alphabetic.

Answer (score 5):

> Bash globbing range in home dir shows content of subdirectories

No, `ls` command shows you content of subdirectories.

> Why is that

Because that is what ls does when given a directory name, it shows the directories content.

> is there a way to suppress this behavior?

From `man ls`:

```
   -d, --directory
          list directories themselves, not their contents
```

Just `ls -d`.

Comment: I don't believe this is what the author is looking for: `ls -d` only shows the directories, but does not show any files.

Comment: Perhaps see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @Dominique The way I understand the question, this is *exactly* what the OP is asking. The `-d` option does not suppress the listing of non-directory entries; it just disables showing the contents of entries which are directories. This is also exactly what the quote from the documentation says.

Comment: `echo [A-Z]*` would probably do the same, except when there are no glob matching files: `ls` would print an error message while `echo` would print `[A-Z]*` if `nullglob` is disabled or an empty string if `nullglob` is enabled.

Comment: `echo [A-Z]* would probably do the same` `ls` can be an alias and also `LS_COLORS`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would like to see all the files and directories but only of the directory I am currently in and not its subdirectories. And it works as I want as long as I am not in my home directory.

Comment: Then just type `ls` with nothing after it. I do not understand.